# Getting CallSid from Twilio in ougoing calls using js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio, voip

I would like to know if there is any way to retrieve CallSid using TwilioJS library from an outgoing call done from a Browser to a Phone. The think is that I'm not able to post anything from my client to my server since I don't have any id of the call.

I've tried to find out the parameters of the connection object:

```
var connection = Twilio.Device.connect()
```

But no CallSid appears there.
Does anyone know how can a get this parameter, or something that lets me to identify the ougoing call that I've just done from js library?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/connection, `connection` should be a `Twilio.Connection` object which has a property named `parameters` with a `CallSid` attribute both for incoming and outgoing connections.

It is probably only available after the connection is made, so you should use an event handler for `connect` event:

```
Twilio.Device.connect(function(connection) {
    var callSid = connection.parameters.CallSid;
});
```

Comment: As you said, connection has parameters, but is not until you disconnect or maybe error as well, that twilio notices you the CallSid.

Comment: @jmolina, apparently it's available only after the connection, please see if the edit to the answer helps.

Comment: Not working for me. 
when I try Twilio.Device.connect(); It's working perfectly but when try this one Twilio.Device.connect(function(connection) {
    var callSid = connection.parameters.CallSid;
}); browser doesn't respond.